# Firebase Notification error not receiving when app is locked when I unlock the phone it receives notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

After implementing the firebase messaging class I am facing a problem that when app is in ideal condition or killed and phone is locked after 2-3 minutes the notification stops receiving as soon as i unlock the phone all the notifications are delivered at a same time.

whats the issue?
i cannot debug?

I tried multiple things let me explain

I tried to debug the code by setting brakepoints and it receives the notification until the app is in forground when i put the app in background or kill the app after 2-3 minutes the app stops receiving notification i checked the logcat and found that the firebase messaging class had an ANR error which i cannot solve its a confuing whats the error to me plus i tried to change the notification priority to High plus i tried to saperate the notificaiton channels for background notification channel and forground notification channel but still not working and finally i found this error in logcat.

here is the ANR error message:

```
ANR in org.twophones
                                                    PID: 14527
                                                    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=org.twophones cmp=org.twophones/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }
                                                    ErrorId: b826eff2-d79b-498d-83cf-f71ef6c9e45a
                                                    Frozen: false
                                                    Load: 0.18 / 0.18 / 0.18
                                                    Output from /proc/pressure/memory 
                                                    some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=865322
                                                    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=607220
                                                 End output from /proc/pressure/memory
                                                    
                                                    CPU usage from 0ms to 11745ms later (2023-09-05 11:28:01.865 to 2023-09-05 11:28:13.610):
                                                      0.2% 950/com.android.bluetooth: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 145 minor
                                                      0.8% 14527/org.twophones: 0% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 86 minor
                                                      3.9% 526/cameraserver: 0% user + 3.9% kernel / faults: 76 minor 1 major
                                                      0.6% 458/audioserver: 0% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 54 minor
                                                      2.9% 626/system_server: 0.1% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 2027 minor
                                                      2% 497/adbd: 0% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 4861 minor
                                                      0.1% 549/media.metrics: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 36 minor
                                                      0.9% 250/logd: 0% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                      0% 129/kswapd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0.8% 430/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.4-service: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
                                                      0.7% 839/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 999 minor
                                                      0.1% 554/mediaserver: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 43 minor
                                                      0% 1/init: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 474/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 30 minor
                                                      0.5% 6080/kworker/u12:2-events_unbound: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                      0.4% 401/statsd: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 32 minor
                                                      0.4% 14948/kworker/u12:4-events_unbound: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                      0.4% 17526/kworker/3:1-mm_percpu_wq: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                      0.3% 13/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                      0% 562/media.swcodec: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2396 minor
                                                      0.3% 1031/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 246 minor
                                                      0% 305/tombstoned: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0.2% 440/android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                      0% 6062/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0.2% 16408/kworker/u12:3-phy1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                      0% 503/drmserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 42 minor
                                                      0.1% 524/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                      0.1% 932/com.android.networkstack.process: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 215 minor
                                                      0% 979/com.android.se: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 166 minor
                                                      0% 6072/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 18117/kworker/3:2-events: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 19/kworker/0:1-events: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 24/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 36/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 56/kcompactd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 297/jbd2/dm-33-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 402/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
                                                      0% 544/media.extractor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1160 minor 4 major
                                                      0% 1643/com.android.emulator.multidisplay: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 237 minor
                                                      0% 6060/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 6064/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 6066/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 6074/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                      0% 6730/com.android.chrome: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor 4 major
                                                      0% 16608/com.google.android.youtube: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    3.4% TOTAL: 0.1% user + 3.3% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% softirq
                                                    CPU usage from 12ms to 282ms later (2023-09-05 11:28:01.877 to 2023-09-05 11:28:02.147):
                                                      16% 626/system_server: 0% user + 16% kernel / faults: 329 minor
                                                        16% 18437/AnrConsumer: 0% user + 16% kernel
                                                      3.7% 24/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 3.7% kernel
                                                    4.3% TOTAL: 0% user + 4.3% kernel
```

i dont knoe what is the issue with the app i cannot find the error properly can some one help me
please be more specific and in details for more understanding.